# OL missing numbers

Tags: html, xhtml

This is going to seem like a stupid question and is basic html but I'm going to ask it anyway. I've seen a few posts that ask this similar question and its not helping fix my issue. I'm working off my local server for testing. I have this for my syntax.

```
<div id="top5">

            <img src="images/top5.png" alt="Top 5 Rankings" />

            <ol>
                <li class="top5rankings"><a href="roster/kidwonder.php">Kid Wonder</a></li>
                <li class="top5rankings"><a href="roster/kidwonder.php">Kid Wonder</a></li>
                <li class="top5rankings"><a href="roster/kidwonder.php">Kid Wonder</a></li>
                <li class="top5rankings"><a href="roster/kidwonder.php">Kid Wonder</a></li>
                <li class="top5rankings"><a href="roster/kidwonder.php">Kid Wonder</a></li>
            </ol>

        </div>
```

However it is not putting the numbers for the ordered list and just seeing if anyone can see my problem. This is what I have applied to the rendered page in my css:

```
li.top5rankings {
color: red;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```

styles.css (line 103)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

styles.css (line 4) Inherited from ol

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `display: block;` so that your css becomes like this instead:

```
li.top5rankings {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good catch; though I've expanded on, and cited, your point in my own answer (without intending to repeat what you've said).

Comment: That worked however can someone explain to me why the display:block creates an issue for this?

Comment: Actually, I don't know :) I have tried googling it but can't really find out why that is... Hm

Comment: I asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257041/why-does-the-list-style-disappear-when-display-block-is-added-to-a-list-item-in .. just out of curiosity

Comment: I think display: block is answered by David below.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using any kind of css-reset stylesheet, it's likely that the `list-style-type` has been removed, or the `margin` has been set to `0`. Try:

```
ol {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

ol li {
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBUNr/1/)

It's also worth noting, as [@Fredrik **does** in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256820/ol-missing-numbers/6256856#6256856), that the `display` property might be causing problems. For `list-elements` the default is:

`display: list-item;`