# Why does the list style disappear when display: block is added to a list item in a list (<ul> or <ol>)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This seems to valid for `display: inline;` and `display: inline-block;` too.

This is what I mean:

```
ul li {
  display: block;
  /* Or display: inline; */
  /* Or display: inline-block; */
}

<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ul>
```

And with list style I mean the actual "bullets" or "numbers" (when `<ol>` is used)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's because normally, `display` is set to `list-item` for `<li>` elements. See the W3C CSS3 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#declaring-a-list-item.

> To declare a list item, the ‘display’ property should be set to ‘list-item’.

Note that you can give arbitrary HTML elements the same behaviour; set `display: list-item` on a `<div>` for example.

Answer (score 13):

An updated solution is to make use of `:before` and `content`.

See this JSfiddle for a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/t72h3/

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
}

<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where did you find that character...in fact how does anyone find any character. unicode..does that has to do something with it.

Comment: In Windows you can use the Character Map program, and on Mac you can use the Font Book. But most of the time I just google what I want!

Comment: i mean character map is like my bookmarks, everything is there but because there is so much i just use search engine to SEARCH....i can't browser all unicodes...or even remember there are things. Though after going through them yesterday i think a whole ui can be made just out of unicodes.

Answer (score 3):

A way to get the effect would be:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="mylink">desc</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: inline-block; /* or block */
}

li a {
    display: list-item;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: What will you do, if you need to put 3 items at `<li>`, not only one `<a>`?

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer is true but doesn't provide a solution and Pappy's is only relevant if you want bullets or easily have access to the what the `li`'s identifier will be. In my case, I need to have an `ol` with `upper-alpha` so that's not possible.

The shortest way around this for us was to put a an inline (`inline`, `inline-block`, `inline-flex`) property as well as `vertical-align: top` on the immediate child of the `li`:

```css
ol {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
  
  > li {
    display: block;
  }
}

.list-item-content {
  display: inline-block; // any inline property will work
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="list-item-content">Some text</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for `ul`

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "• ";
}

<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ul>
```

Solution for `ol` using [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    counter-reset: my-counter;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) ". ";
}

<ol>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property "float:left" for Li(s) to display a list horizontally.
no need to assign "display:block" property.
you can give margin-left or right property to set spaces between text and style shape.

```css
li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```