# using display optiions in css removes numbers and bullets

Tags: html, css

I'm just learning html5 and css3 when I create a simple page with either an ordered list or an unordered list and apply css display: inline; or block; it removes the numbers or bullets does anyone know why?

Comment: A simple code snippet would be helpful. Do you apply `display:none` to the ul / ol element or li?

Answer (score 2):

This answer has been answered many times. Here's [one of the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257041/why-does-the-list-style-disappear-when-display-block-is-added-to-a-list-item-in) given by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

However, you can use something like this and it'll workout.

```
ul.columns>li:before { content:'\ffed'; margin-right:10px; }
```

or

You can also use background image. However, I'd suggest the former method.

Answer (score 1):

list style bullets works only for `display: list-item` applied elements. This property is applied by default to the li element, which you are overriding now by applying `display: inline or block`. Hence, the list style icons will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Because only list items have bullets/number points. It doesn't make sense for an inline box or a block box to have a bullet, because neither of those things is a list item.

List items are `display: list-item`; that's what gives them the bullets/number points.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of give
display :inline;

You can apply 
Float left to li and give padding to it

Eg.
    ul li{
           float:left;
           padding:0 25px 0 0;
          }