# Bullet points are not displayed

Tags: html, css

I guess this should be a simple question, but I just don't get it done.

I have a ul with li's and I want to use bullet points here, but they just won't be displayed, even though I included them in my CSS.

HTML looks like that:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  if (!isset($_SESSION["email"])) {
    header('Location: ../login_error.php');
    exit;
  }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The A Room</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="explanations" id="explanation_qas">
    <p>
      Blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla     blabla blabla blabla
        <ul >
          <li class="explanation_list">blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla</li>
          <li class="explanation_list">blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla</li>
          <li class="explanation_list">blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla </li>
        </ul>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS looks like that:

```
html, body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #A9E2F3;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-color: white;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    top: 1%;
    right: 20%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;    
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%; 
    padding-left: 7%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    border-width: 0.15em;
}

.explanations {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    color: #A9E2F3;
    width: 31%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2.5%;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    border-width: 0.15em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

#explanation_qas {
    top: 15%;
}

#explanation_sources {
    top: 74%;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 30%;
}

.explanation_list {
    background-color: black;
}

.explanation_list:hover {
    color: #A9E2F3;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I highly appreciate it!

Comment: What browser are you using, Also can you post an example on JSFiddle or CodePen? I can't seem to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: list-item;` css property is default for `<li>` tag. By applying `display: inline-block` you're overriding it, which causes bullet points to disappear.  You should use a pseudo class to solve your problem:

```
ul.explanations>li:before{
    content: "";
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the display property on the li should be

```
display: list-item;
```

instead of

```
 display: inline-block;
```

(see [W3C CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#declaring-a-list-item.))

If you want your li element to stay inline-block , you could use :before and content

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
}

<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ul>
```

as pappy suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257041/why-does-the-list-style-disappear-when-display-block-is-added-to-a-list-item-in).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use display:inline-block, because of this bullets are disappearing.